# How to remove all cell formatting

Tags: macos, numbers

How can all formatting be removed from a sheet in Numbers so each cell only contains the text, with links no longer clickable?

Comment: have you tried exporting to CSV and then importing it right back in? CSV is *text only*

Comment: The exported CSV is correctly formatted. This is about using Numbers with some enhancements disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove hyperlinks, [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250058113) post (the first result of [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=numbers+remove+all+hyper+links) Google search) should help. Summarized below:

1. Select all cells using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or Edit -> Select All)
2. Copy cells using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ( or Edit -> Copy)
3. Paste and Match Style using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+ <kbd>⇧</kbd> +<kbd>V</kbd> (or Edit -> Paste and Match Style)

This will remove all hyperlinks, however it will keep formatting like Bold, Italics, etc. If you want all formatting to be gone, use the suggestion from [Steve Chambers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/33273/steve-chambers) to export to CSV and import from CSV, as the [CSV Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) is just plain text and doesn't save any formatting.

1. File -> Export to -> CSV...
2. Select the CSV you just exported in Finder and right click -> Open With -> Numbers

This will completely open a new Numbers document without formatting, unless you have Numbers set to automatically detect hyperlinks. If you do not want hyperlinks to be detected:

1. Open Numbers preferences using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (or Numbers -> Preferences...)
2. Go to the Auto-Correction tab and uncheck "Automatically detect links" under the Formatting section

Comment: I've got the Autodetect link off, but it still converts them, and adds header styling, on import from CSV. It may be that email addresses are treated differently than URLs. Could a blank template be set as the default?

Comment: The link removal process does work.

Comment: The CSV option will remove the formulas, if any, in addition to formatting.